# shared preferences not working on a specific phone

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

am new to android programming and am creating an app that requires authentication. i am storing the auth details in shred preferences and its working fine.  So i tried to test the app on different phones and its not working on a specific phone. i tried to checking my code for any errors but its fine. The app works fine in other phones except one. my question is, what might cause storing to shared preferences not to work on a specific phone, i have done lots of research and i haven't found any leads to what might be the problem. Someone please help me out or point me on the right direction.

here is the class that am using to access shared preferences

```
    package ke.co.intellect.emergencyke.emergencyke.helper;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;

import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created by gakami on 5/28/17.
 */

public class PrefManager {
    // Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences pref;

    // Editor for Shared preferences
    Editor editor;

    // Context
    Context _context;

    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Shared preferences file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "OneEmergency";

    // All Shared Preferences Keys
    private static final String KEY_IS_WAITING_FOR_SMS = "IsWaitingForSms";
    private static final String KEY_MOBILE_NUMBER = "mobile_number";
    private static final String KEY_IS_LOGGED_IN = "isLoggedIn";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_TOKEN = "token";
    private static final String KEY_MOBILE = "mobile";

    public PrefManager(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    public void setIsWaitingForSms(boolean isWaiting) {
        editor.putBoolean(KEY_IS_WAITING_FOR_SMS, isWaiting);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean isWaitingForSms() {
        return pref.getBoolean(KEY_IS_WAITING_FOR_SMS, false);
    }

    public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
        editor.putString(KEY_MOBILE_NUMBER, mobileNumber);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getMobileNumber() {
        return pref.getString(KEY_MOBILE_NUMBER, null);
    }

    public void createLogin(String name, String mobile, String token) {
        editor.putString(KEY_NAME, name);
        editor.putString(KEY_MOBILE, mobile);
        editor.putString(KEY_TOKEN, token);
        editor.putBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGGED_IN, true);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return pref.getBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGGED_IN, false);
    }

    public void clearSession() {
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
        HashMap<String, String> profile = new HashMap<>();
        profile.put("name", pref.getString(KEY_NAME, null));
        profile.put("token", pref.getString(KEY_TOKEN, null));
        profile.put("mobile", pref.getString(KEY_MOBILE, null));
        return profile;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which device? What is the problem? What is not working on that device?

Comment: what is the device ?

Comment: TECNO - N8S , android version 6.0

Comment: i can not store anything in the shared preferences.

Comment: Are you found any answer?

Comment: no, i haven't found the solution.